# Too many exceptions in LOG file

Tags: exception, logging, websphere

I found too many FileNotFoundException in LOG file like below. although Error has no real negative impact except for being an annoyance,and cluttering the logs.

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper doFilter SRVE8109W: Uncaught exception thrown by filter AnyChart Resources: java.io.FileNotFoundException

can anyone help me....

Comment: Can you just catch the exception in your servlet filter so it doesn't get caught by the web container instead?

Comment: You have to check in that case why you have so many requests to your AnyChart filter for non existing resources. That my indicate problem in your application, better fix the application than try to hide exceptions in log

Answer (score 0):

In-order to get rid of those exception logs we have suppressed the by creating a custom property in the web-sphere.

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressLoggingFileNotFoundExceptions = true

Please see the following link for more details: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM64368